# Set links during XML rebot parsing

Tags: python, robotframework

Here is the situation: I have a django backend running tests, creating XML files, and sending them to my django frontend, which does whatever he wants with them (actually generates HTML files).

**[ backend ]** -> XML -> **[frontend]** -> HTML

My problem is: In the XML files, I have external links to my documentation which, is hosted by my frontend and whose URL is only known by the latter.

How can I configure my '.robot' file to create elements to be changed by rebot during the processing of the XML file, and what are the arguments i need to give to rebot ?

**EDIT:**
As asked in the comments, here is an example:

My robot file actually contains a test like this:

```
Test_1
  [Documentation]Doc: [${PathToRefDoc}#test_1 | test_1_doc]
  <:Do Things:>
```

The ${PathToRefDoc} value is replaced during the generation of the XML file and it gives something like this:

```
<test id="1" name="Test_1"
    <doc>Doc: [<:ref doc URL:>#test_1 | test_1_doc]</doc>
    <:Infos on things done:>
</test>
```

I want to have the XML file without the <:ref doc URL:> value being already set, as it's value is not known during the creation of the file but as a "macro" which should be given during the processing of the XML file by rebot.

Comment: Can you provide a code example of what it is you want to do? Presently it's unclear what you functionally want to achieve and what the role of Robot Framework is in this.

Comment: I wrote an example. After searching more carefully, I have found the 'prerebotmodifier' classes. I think it may be what I seek, but I am not sure about it, and the documentation seems unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution in the API documentation of robotframework repository:

[Robotframework ouput documentation](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/userguide/src/ExecutingTestCases/OutputFiles.rst#programmatic-modification-of-results)

I needed to create a class inheriting the class SuiteVisitor, here is the code

```
from robot.api import SuiteVisitor

class DocURLSetter(SuiteVisitor):
    """
    Changes every instances of ${PathToRefDoc} contained in the tests
    documentation with the URL given at instantiation
    """

    def __init__(self, doc_url):
        self.doc_url = doc_url

    def visit_test(self, test):
        test.doc = test.doc.replace("${PathToRefDoc}", self.doc_url)
```

And in the code calling rebot framework, I had to add the 'prerebotmodifier' argument:

```
robot.rebot(src, log=dst,
            report=None,
            loglevel='TRACE:WARN',
            exclude='TEST_SKIPPED',
            stdout=None,
            stderr=None,
            prerebotmodifier=DocURLSetter(my_doc_url))
```